# How to make this oval shape in css3

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #5e2424;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 178px;
    border-radius: 694px 208px 0px 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    top: -199px;
}
```

How to make this oval like in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo element

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 556px;
  height: 363px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHNBX.png);
  background: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: -45%;
  width: 180%;
  height: 200%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Can you please do this in the same image i provide you ?